# Real time data using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, real-time

I have a real time data feed of health patient data that I connect to with python. I want to run some sklearn algorithms over this data feed so that I can predict in real time if someone is going to get sick. Is there a standard way in which one connects real time data to sklearn? I have traditionally had static datasets and never an incoming stream so this is quite new to me. If anyone has sort of some general rules/processes/tools used that would be great.

Comment: You could look into hooking up a feed from your health patient database to your machine and use generators to stream the data in at a given time interval.

Comment: @not_a_robot thank you I will look into those.

Comment: Related: [Strategies to scale computationally: bigger data](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

Answer (score 2):

With most algorithms training is slow and predicting is fast. Therefore it is better to train offline using training data; and then use the trained model to predict each new case in real time.

Obviously you might decide to train again later if you acquire more/better data. However there is little benefit in retraining after every case.

Answer (score 2):

It is feasible to train the model from a static dataset and predict classifications for incoming data with the model. Retraining the model with each new set of patient data not so much. Also breaks the train/test mode of testing a ML model.

Trained models can be saved to file and imported in the code used for real time prediction.

In python scikit learn, this is via the pickle package.
R programming saves to an rda object. saveRDS

yay... my first answering a ML question!